# How to get updated data from task editor widget from custom field in bryntum gantt chart library

Tags: javascript, salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc, bryntum-scheduler

I have created a Gantt chart using bryntum library, it's a very good library so far, all although there are many topics that I am not able to understand from their official documentation,
Like I have added one custom field called phase in the task editor widget where I am passing picklist values from the apex and now the user is able to select different phases for each task using the task editor widget, however, I am still not able to find it how we can get the updated data list from the widget so I can update it in the backend.
thanks in advance..[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so at last I found the data for this new field called Phase inside Gantt.data object and I had to manually put that data inside a map and used it later at the time when I did DML.